# Get weights of each search term for full text search in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of documents indexed in elastic. I also have a query that scores the indexed documents based on a given search term. The search term has multiple words in it. Is there a way to return the weightage of the search terms with respect to the indexed documents which ultimately scores each of the documents?

Or at least return the most relevant keywords that defined the search and score for each of them.

Comment: could you show an example of expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at the [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html); given a query and a document, it will provide an explanation of the score, broken down into its constituent parts.

The Explain API can be quite verbose for more complex queries, but should provide all of the information that you're asking for.